# make sure slf4j captures stack traces in the log files

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, slf4j

Let's say I have simple code:

```
public static void Main(){
throw new NullPointerException("this is an npe");
}
```

How with slf4j do you make sure that that exception is logged to the log file. Is there a default setting in spring that you can set in application properties, or in the logback file, that makes sure this gets captured, even though it is not in the try catch?

Please note, I am NOT looking for a solution to a webcontroller, or how to use log.error(). I know how to do those. I am looking for an overarching setting so that we don't lose exceptions throughout the application. This can apply to OOM, or printing a heap dump etc. I am including spring as a tag just in case the solution is in the applications.properties, as this is a spring project.

Comment: So are you not looking for a global exception handler too?

Comment: Sure. Something that will catch every exception. I tried doing something like Thread.setUncaught... but it only worked on that current thread

Comment: I added an answer, hope the below helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok as you have said, you can add a controller advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class YourCustomHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
   // you can do logs here and pass a custom object that will parse to json object
    return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
}

@ExceptionHandler(YourCustomException.class)
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleTthException(
        YourCustomException ex, Locale locale) {
    
    return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
}

private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(ApiError apiError) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, apiError.getStatus());
}
```

}

Comment: Is this a global error handler? Would it catch an OOM error? or a stack overflow in a random thread? seems mostly related to web requests?

Comment: I said I was specifically looking for something broader than a crontroller device?

Answer (score 0):

Based off of this: https://sysgears.com/articles/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-writing-to-a-log4j-appender/, I have found something I believe works.

At beginning of psvm:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(new LoggingOutputStream(), true));
}
```

This says to print errors to my LoggingOutputStream.
Code for this class:

```
public class LoggingOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    /**
     * Default number of bytes in the buffer.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH = 2048;

    /**
     * Indicates stream state.
     */
    private boolean hasBeenClosed = false;

    /**
     * Internal buffer where data is stored.
     */
    private byte[] buf;

    /**
     * The number of valid bytes in the buffer.
     */
    private int count;

    /**
     * Remembers the size of the buffer.
     */
    private int curBufLength;

    /**
     * The logger to write to.
     */
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingOutputStream.class);
    public LoggingOutputStream(){
        curBufLength = DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH;
        buf = new byte[curBufLength];
        count = 0;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Writes the specified byte to this output stream.
     *
     * @param b the byte to write
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    public void write(final int b) throws IOException {
        if (hasBeenClosed) {
            log.error("The stream has been closed.");
            throw new IOException("The stream has been closed.");
        }
        // don't log nulls
        if (b == 0) {
            return;
        }
        // would this be writing past the buffer?
        if (count == curBufLength) {
            // grow the buffer
            final int newBufLength = curBufLength +
                    DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH;
            final byte[] newBuf = new byte[newBufLength];
            System.arraycopy(buf, 0, newBuf, 0, curBufLength);
            buf = newBuf;
            curBufLength = newBufLength;
        }

        buf[count] = (byte) b;
        count++;
    }

    /**
     * Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output
     * bytes to be written out.
     */
    @Override
    public void flush() {
        if (count == 0) {
            return;
        }
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[count];
        System.arraycopy(buf, 0, bytes, 0, count);
        String str = new String(bytes);
        log.error(str);
        count = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Closes this output stream and releases any system resources
     * associated with this stream.
     */
    @Override
    public void close() {
        flush();
        hasBeenClosed = true;
    }
}
```

Now, all errors are "intercepted" and routed to my log file.